# Problem to connect to a remote MySQL database to alter a table with Percona Toolkit

Tags: mysql, percona

I want to alter a huge table with percona toolkit from my local machine.

To do so, I write this command:

```
pt-online-schema-change --dry-run --user user --ask-pass --alter "alter table table add column column1 varchar(255)" h=mysql.remote.com,D=database,t=table;
```

When I execute this command, I have this error:

```
Cannot connect to MySQL: DBI connect('database;host=mysql.remote.com;mysql_read_default_group=client','user',...) failed: Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON. at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/percona-toolkit/3.5.1/libexec/bin/pt-online-schema-change line 2345.
```

I don't find information on how to disable ssl verification or how to configure it.

How can I do?